# Getting error while deploying maven project

Tags: maven, maven-2, liferay, liferay-6

While deploying, I am getting this error using this command:

> mvn clean package install liferay:deploy -U -DskipTests

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) on project basic-details-nok-form-portlet: Failed to install metadata us.nok.mic.hrm.portal.po
rtlet:basic-details-nok-form-portlet/maven-metadata.xml: Could not parse metadata C:\Users\NOKIA_ADMIN\.m2\repository\us\nok\mic\hrm\portal\portlet\basic-details-nok-form-portlet\maven-metadata-local.xml:
 only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not \u0 (position: START_DOCUMENT seen \u0... @1:1) -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the pom.xml file in editor that allows showing enhanced view (or just in hex). There should be a character at the very beginning that isn't visible under normal circumstances.
Or you could just try to cut out a line or two and rewrite it manually, I'm not sure if it will actually get rid of said character, so it's probably better to stick to the first method.